# Por qué no puedo ver en Github tal cual el proyecto web que veo en mí PC

Tags: bootstrap, github

El proyecto en mi computadora (página web hecha con Html/CSS/Bootstrap y usé Visual Studio Code) no coincide con los archivos que subí y se muestra en Github o Netlify. Es decir, el sitio web no tomó lo que se hizo con Bootstrap (carrusel, pie de página y forma), por lo que al abrir el enlace web en Github y Netlify me muestra un sitio web deformado. Lo intenté todo y no sé qué pasa! ¿Será un problema de la ubicación de carpetas de Bootstrap?... ¿Cuál será el problema?

- https://entrega-proyecto-final-cac.netlify.app/
- https://lorenzasf.github.io/proyecto_final/
- (video demostration Google Drive):
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HJwR-AubsPbg8frD1XuXAMFeLq8buaAq/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Intenta ver el inspector dando click derecho opciones de desarrollador->consola a ver que no carga, o abriendo tu web local desde modo incognito dado que chrome guarda los css en cache si sigue igual as lo mismo en la version online

Comment: Gracias Bryro por tu respuesta, ya solucioné el problema. Me sirvió tu recomendación, efectivamente a través de la consola en el navegador web pude ver los errores del sitio web y el problema era con los 3 archivos de Bootstrap que estaban guardados en carpetas erróneas,  además "bootstrap.bundle.min.js" en el <script> ubicado antes de cerrar el </body> lo cambié de ubicación y lo agregué antes de cerrar el </head> y todo funcionó, ahora la web muestra los archivos como corresponde sin deformarse lo realizado con Bootstrap (navbar, carrousel, formulario y footer). Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En la consola del navegador pone:
Ha fallado la carga del  con origen "https://lorenzasf.github.io/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js".

es decir, no es capaz de encontrar este archivo, mira a ver como está la ruta.....

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias  Willian por tu respuesta, ya solucioné el problema. Me sirvió tu recomendación, efectivamente a través de la consola en el navegador web pude ver los errores del sitio web y el problema era con los 3 archivos de Bootstrap que estaban guardados en carpetas erróneas,  además "bootstrap.bundle.min.js" en el <script> ubicado antes de cerrar el </body> lo cambié de ubicación y lo agregué antes de cerrar el </head> y todo funcionó, ahora la web muestra los archivos como corresponde sin deformarse lo realizado con Bootstrap (navbar, carrousel, formulario y footer). Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo subiste a github mediante comandos git ( git push )

-mira bien que en el .gitignore no le estes prohibiendo leer los archivos de bootstrap o node depende como lo pusieras.

-Si lo subiste desde la pagina web github mejor intenta hacerlo por comandos, github lo tiene bien explicado ( git init, git add, git commit, git push) te dejo link para tutorial rapido [aqui](https://gist.github.com/cgonzalezdai/cc33db72a6fe5178637aabb562eae35c)

-Si quieres confirmar que esta bien tu codigo, usa la libreria de bootstrap de forma remota puedes verlas [aqui](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Hola HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" integrity="sha512-a+PObWRxNVh4HZR9wijCGj84JgJ/QhZ8dET09REfYz2clUBjKYhGbOmdy9KEHilYKgbMSIHNQEsonv/r75mHXw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hola Mundo!</p>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-6'>
      left
      </div>
      <div class='col-6'>
      right
      </div>
      </div>
    
    
    
    <!--puedes colocarla abajo del body para que carge despues de leer el html o en el head pero poniendo defer al final-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-5BqtYqlWfJemW5+v+TZUs22uigI8tXeVah5S/1Z6qBLVO7gakAOtkOzUtgq6dsIo5c0NJdmGPs0H9I+2OHUHVQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

-Prueba usando otros navegadores y que no tenga blockers